# All 6-Number Permutations from a List

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, recursion, permutation

I'm writing a program, and the goal is to take a list of numbers and return all the six-letter combinations for it using a recursive function (without importing a function to do it for me). Say, for example, my numbers are "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9", output would be:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 4 5 8
1 2 3 4 5 9
1 2 3 4 6 7
1 2 3 4 6 8
1 2 3 4 6 9
1 2 3 4 7 8
... etcetera, all the way down to
4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I'm not looking for code, persay, just a push in the right direction conceptually. What I've attempted thus far has failed and I've driven myself into a logical rut.

I've included the code I used before below, but it isn't really a recursive function and only seems to work for 6-8-digit values. It's very messy, and I'd be fine with scrapping it entirely:

```
# Function prints all the possible 6-number combinations for a group of numbers
def lotto(constantnumbers, variablenumbers):
    # Base case: No more constant variables, or only 6 numbers to begin with
    if len(constantnumbers) == 0 or len(variablenumbers) == 0:    
        if len(constantnumbers) == 0:
            print(" ".join(variablenumbers[1:7]))
        else:
            print(" ".join(constantnumbers[0:6]))
        i = 6 - len(constantnumbers)
        outvars = variablenumbers[1:i + 1]
        if len(variablenumbers) > len(outvars) + 1:
            print(" ".join(constantnumbers + outvars))
            for index in range(len(outvars), 0, -1):
                outvars[index - 1] = variablenumbers[index + 1]
                print(" ".join(constantnumbers + outvars))
    else:
        i = 6 - len(constantnumbers)
        outvars = variablenumbers[1:i + 1]
        print(" ".join(constantnumbers + outvars))
        if len(variablenumbers) > len(outvars) + 1:
            for index in range(len(outvars), 0, -1):
                outvars[index - 1] = variablenumbers[index + 1]
                print(" ".join(constantnumbers + outvars))
        #Reiterates the function until there are no more constant numbers
        lotto(constantnumbers[0:-1], constantnumbers[-1:] + variablenumbers)
```

Comment: Why are you working with strings instead of integers?

Comment: Within the context of the question, it doesn't really matter. It should, theoretically, be able to work with letters of the alphabet too.

Comment: Well no, not per say. I just don't think that makes for readable code. You can make the function work with numbers inputted as strings by converting them to integers in the beginning.

Comment: Regardless, I'm more concerned with the structure of the recursive function itself and how I should implement it. If integers will make it more readable, then I'll definitely implement it with them once I actually have a clue what I'm doing. I'm still really lost as to how the function should work in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import itertools

for combo in itertools.combinations(range(1,10), 6):
    print(" ".join(str(c) for c in combo))
```

which gives

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 7
1 2 3 4 5 8
...
3 4 6 7 8 9
3 5 6 7 8 9
4 5 6 7 8 9
```

**Edit:** ok, here is a recursive definition:

```
def combinations(basis, howmany):
    for index in range(0, len(basis) - howmany + 1):
        if howmany == 1:
            yield [basis[index]]
        else:
            this, remainder = basis[index], basis[index+1:]
            for rest in combinations(remainder, howmany - 1):
                yield [this] + rest
```

**Edit2:**

Base case: A 1-item combination is any basis item.

Induction: An N-item combination is any basis item plus an (N-1)-item combination from the remaining basis.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to do it with my own function rather than by importing one.

Comment: itertools is part of the standard python library.  Why not import?

Comment: Exactly. I'm trying to practice recursion, and I'd like to be able to see how it works for myself.

Comment: I'm afraid the "yield" concept is a bit beyond me with my current programming experience. I'd find a simple outline of how the recursive call should work (ie) what is the base case?, how do I iterate through it? etc.) much more helpful.

Comment: @user3361007: no time like the present to learn ;-)  You can think of yield as "return a value, and then continue from the same spot the next time the function is called". It converts your function to a generator, which returns a series of values instead of a list of values, which means you don't have to use up memory storing the values until you are ready for them.